# TypeError no INSERT via Python no PostgreSQL

Tags: python, json, postgresql

Estou com o seguinte codigo

```
import json
import io
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect("dados da conexão")
connection.autocommit = True
cursor = connection.cursor()

readTest = io.open("arquivo.json", encoding = "utf-8")
readAll = readTest.readlines()

cursor. executemany("INSERT INTO tabela (coluna) VALUES (%s)",(readAll))
```

Quando faço o INSERT do arquivo.json com uma unica linha o mesmo funciona porem ao usar mais de 2 linhas o mesmo apareçe o seguinte erro:

```
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
```

Exemplo de conteudo do arquivo.json com mais de duas linhas

```
{"id":"BRA","count":2,"distance":0.8,"longitude":-80.004114}
{"id":"USA","count":9,"distance":1.2,"longitude":-20.011111}
```

Comment: Para mais de uma linha você não utiliza o `execute`, mas sim o `executemany`.

Comment: Fiz a mudança para executemany e ainda consta o mesmo erro da pergunta( vou mudar na pergunta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode inserir linha por linha, bastando usar um `for`:

```
with open("arquivo.json", encoding="utf-8") as arq:
   for linha in arq:
       cursor.execute("INSERT INTO tabela (coluna) VALUES (%s)", (linha,))
```

Repare na virgula em `(linha,)`, essa virgula é muito importante pois cria uma tupla de um único elemento, que é o que o `execute` pede.

Caso prefira usar o `executemany` precisa passar uma lista de tuplas, cada uma com um elemento:

```
with open("arquivo.json", encoding="utf-8") as arq:
    lista_de_tuplas = [(linha,) for linha in arq]
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO tabela (coluna) VALUES (%s)", lista_de_tuplas)
```

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda o mesmo funcionou perfeitamente. Só estou apreensivo pois o mesmo  tem muitas linhas e esta demorando demais para fazer a inserção (São 90000 linhas) em um arquivo de 490mb